# Components suddenly disappear after reopening the project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I'm using c# visual studio 2012. What could be the reason why my `TabControl` suddenly disappear after I reopen the project file? And how could I get it back without creating all over? Thanks in advance.

Comment: *components suddenly disappear ...* what does that means?

Comment: textboxes, label, tabcontrol are missing on my form